# I have a Bitcoin ABC full node. How do I split off Bitcoin SV?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, blockchain-fork, ecash, bitcoin-sv

I have some BCH in a Bitcoin ABC full node, which is currently running 0.18.5. I want to obtain the corresponding Bitcoin SV without spending on both chains at the same time and losing the BSV. I am capable of running a Bitcoin SV full node, with the same or a different wallet. Is it safe to spend these coins as is, or is there some special process for splitting them?

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any useful information online, other than "send it to an exchange" which I really don't want to do. Even bitcoincash.org has no useful information and seems to want to pretend that nothing significant even happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a tool (linked by user MCCCS) but you can actually do the splitting in regular Electron Cash too. Electron Cash is great for this because unlike most wallets, you can connect to both BCH and BSV servers. Just get some free BCH-only 'split dust' from free.bitcoin.com or from forkfaucet.cash, and mix that with your coins. Then switch to BSV and make a distinct transaction there.

The key points are:

- During splitting, only send amongst your own addresses. That way if you screw up, you haven't lost anything.
- After splitting, wait then verify that your coins are split (have different transaction IDs)

Some guides:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/btc/comments/9yefov/if_you_want_to_dump_bsv_some_tips_on_splitting/
- https://news.bitcoin.com/follow-this-branch-a-guide-to-splitting-bch-and-bsv/
- https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/412369923541565463/514774626849521672/bsvbch-2.pdf

Comment: To be clear, it's not necessary to do an OP_MUL split coin? After I do the OP_CHECKDATASIG split, I can then just go into the SV wallet and sweep my balance to myself and that's it?

Comment: Correct, once you have made a transaction on BCH chain (and it has confirmed), then you can make an incompatible transaction on the SV chain. That SV transaction can't be replayed back onto BCH since on the BCH chain those inputs are already spent.

Answer (score 1):

https://btc.com/tools/replay

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Answer (score 1):

Amaclin's answer is probably the easiest way, but here's a second way, which doesn't require trust: [Using Lundeberg's fork of Electron Cash](https://github.com/markblundeberg/coinsplitter_checkdatasig/releases)